# "The single scalar stored by an LSTM or GRU memory cell" - Deep learning book

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, gated-recurrent-unit

I am reading [Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville, and on page 413, they discuss how to store information using a framework such as a neural Turing machine. Quote:

> Neural networks excel at storing implicit knowledge, but they struggle to memorize facts. Stochastic gradient descent requires many presentations of the same input before it can be stored in neural network parameters, and even then, that input will not be stored especially precisely. ...

> To resolve this diﬃculty, Weston et al. (2014) introduced memory networks that include a set of memory cells that can be accessed via an addressing mechanism. Memory networks originally required a supervision signal instructing them how to use their memory cells. Graves et al. (2014) introduced the neural Turing machine, which is able to learn to read from and write arbitrary content to memory cells without explicit supervision about which actions to undertake, and allowed end-to-end training without this supervision signal, via the use of a content-based soft attention mechanism ...

> These memory cells are typically augmented to contain a vector, **rather than the single scalar stored by an LSTM or GRU memory cell.**

(emphasis by me)

Why do they claim that LSTM or GRU only stores a scalar? I thought they could also contain a vector. Am I misunderstanding what they are talking about?

Comment: "LSTM" can refer to a layer or a unit. In one case, you will have vectors, in the other, you will have scalars. I'd need to double check the specifics, though, because it's been a while since I dealt with this. I'll let someone else provide a more complete answer.